# How would I find the time complexity of this recursive algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, time, complexity-theory

I'm trying to figure out this homework problem but I'm so confused. I need to find the time complexity of this algorithm ClosestPair, but I can't figure out how to calculate how many times it will run. Here's what I have so far:

```
1. ClosestPair(S, p, r)
2.  if p == r 
3.      return ∞
4.  if r - p == 1
5.      return Distance(S[p], S[p+1])
6.  else
7.      m = floor ((p+r)/2) //m is the index of the median (the x-coordinate is the vertical dividing line)
8.      d1 = ClosestPair(S, p, m)
9.      d2 = ClosestPair(S, m+1, r)
10.     d = min(d1, d2)
11.     SPrime = points in S within distance d from S[m].x sorted by y.
12.     dPrime = BandClosestPair(Sprime, d)
13.     return min( dPrime, d)
```

Here is my time complexity so far

```
1. 0
2. 1
3. 1
4. 1
5. 1
6. 1
7. 1
8. 
9.
10. 1 (It's not actually 1 but it will be a constant so it won't affect the algorithm's time complexity)
11. 
12.
13. 1
```

Any help would be awesome! I don't want you to do the homework for me just some help figuring it out:)

Comment: Generally you'd look for loops or things that repeat for a set of objects/values like recursion. However, all the method calls like ClosestPair, min, BandCloestPair, Distance, need to be evaluated too. So you need to look at the implementation of those methods.

Comment: It's very difficult to compute the complexity yourself since it depends on geometric properties of the plane (specifically that BandClosestPair is O(n)). It's unreasonable as a homework question unless you're expected to google rather than prove the answer. There's a solution and proof here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closest_pair_of_points_problem

Comment: @Brion That's the weird thing I didn't get any info on BandClosestPair, Distance is just a simple point dist equation using Sqrt.

Comment: @PaulHankin My issue is that I understand how the algorithm works, but I don't get how to figure out how many times it will run. It seems like it will keep splitting the points up until it finds a subarray that only has 1 point but depending on where the points are placed and how spread out they are it could split any number of times right?

Comment: @Diericx No. Each split halves the size of the array, and the location of the points does not affect the recursion at all (only the working of BandClosestPair). Are you sure you understand how the algorithm works? It's explained quite thoroughly on the wikipedia page above, but I'm sure there's other references you can check out.

Answer (score -1):

This is probably what you are looking for. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem

There is also a good lecture on this topic on Coursera by Tim Roughgarden.
https://www.coursera.org/learn/algorithm-design-analysis